# VBA Insert whole ADODB.Recordset into table

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run SQL query on sql server (some DWH) and then insert outcome into access table (using VBA).
I did it by using ADODB.Connection, ADODB.Command and ADODB.Recordset. At this point I have my outcome in Recordset and I Wonder how I can insert it into table without looping it.
I tried:

```
If Not (Rs.EOF And Rs.BOF) Then  
    Rs.MoveFirst  
    Do Until Rs.EOF = True  
        DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO Table (F1, F2) VALUES ( " & rs![F1] & ", " & rs[F2] & ")" 
        Rs.MoveNext  
    Loop  
End If
```

But Recordset may have over 100k rows. So it would take ages to insert it by using this method.

Another very fast way is to open a new excel workbook paste it into worksheet and then import it. But I would like to avoid it. Is there any other way ?

---------EDITED-----------
Sorry guys. My bad. I was forcing solution with VBA while linkin it was perfect. THANKS !

Comment: Why make a copy in Access, it is way to slow and dies with that kind of rows. If you want create a SQL view, and link Access to that view. It still will be slow.

Comment: Few reasons:
1.) I got no rights for creating views at SQL Servers (read-only)
2.) Access will be used by users with no SQL knowledge
3.) VBA will make few other actions depend on user decision

Comment: Ok, then run your query in SQL, right click in the results page, and pick copy (no headers). Open the Access table and click on the last row and paste.

Comment: 1.) It's going to be a tool for users with no SQL knowledge (including software)
2.) It's going to be updated frequently. So doing it manually it's a waste of time and it's inconvenient
3.) My politics: Don't do things which can be done automatically.

Comment: Why don't you just link the SQL table(s) to Access and then make a query with the values you want? That's the same as having a view in SQL server in functionality (but not in performance).

Answer (score 3):

> I was wondering if there is any as fast way which use Access
>   resources only.

As already mentioned, *link* the SQL table, then create a simple *append* query that reads from the linked table and writes to your Access table, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the commenters that you should link if at all possible. But I wanted to see if it could be done. I ended up converting the recordset to a comma delimited file and use `TransferText` to append it.

```
Public Sub ImportFromSQLSvr()

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim sResult As String
    Dim sFile As String, lFile As Long

    Const sIMPORTFILE As String = "TestImport.txt"

    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open msCONN
    Set rs = cn.Execute("SELECT SiteID, StoreNumber FROM Site")

    'Add a header row, replace tabs with commas
    sResult = rs.GetString
    sResult = "SiteID, StoreNumber" & vbNewLine & sResult
    sResult = Replace(sResult, vbTab, ",")

    'Write to a text file
    lFile = FreeFile
    sFile = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & sIMPORTFILE
    Open sFile For Output As lFile
        Print #lFile, sResult
    Close lFile

    'Append to table dbo_Site
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "dbo_Site", Environ("TEMP") & "\" & sIMPORTFILE, True

    On Error Resume Next
        rs.Close
        Set rs = Nothing
        cn.Close
        Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you have any commas in your data, you'll need to do some extra work to properly format the csv.

Comment: I tired that. The xlsx/csv files are the fastest way I came up with. Solutions for commas is adding proper Import/Export specification (for example add record in "MSysIMEXspecs" ).  
But I was wondering if there is any as fast way which use Access resources only.